# Sencha ExtJS checkbox model based on value

Tags: extjs, checkbox, gridpanel

I'm using Sencha ExtJS and I added grid panel with check box model. I want to disable some check boxes based on grid panel value. I haven't seen renderer option for checkbox model.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution. Override the checkbox selection model

```
 renderer: function(val, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
     var status = record.data['status'];
     if(status == 's'){
          meta.tdCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-cell-special';
          return '<div class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-row-checker">&#160;</div>';   
     } else {
          return null;   
     }
}
```

source: http://extjswithsandeesh.blogspot.com/2012/05/display-checkboxes-for-selected-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using extJs-4, it is there: [checkbox model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel)

and for extJs-3 you find it here: [checkbox model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel)

Comment: thnaks, Anyway I didn't see any methods using for my implementation. I'm using sencha extjs 4.2.